# Touchwiz relaunches application instead of resuming them

Tags: android, android-launcher, samsung-touchwiz

I noticed a strange issue with my app on a Galaxy S4 LTE updated to Android 4.4.2.
If i go back to the launcher with the home button and try to reopen my application from the launcher menu, it restarts from the main activity instead of resuming from where it was send on background. Issue isn't present if I go back on my app from the task manager.

The issue isn't present on my Nexus devices (7 2012 with some months old CM11 build and 5 with last Cyanogenmod rom) and another Samsung Device (Galaxy Ace 2 I8160 running 4.1.2) I tested my app on.

Other apps behaviour are correct on the Galaxy S4 (IE: Facebook resumes correctly) so I think I'm missing some flags on my AndroidManifest.xml. Any help?

Comment: were you able to figure out what is going on? We're seeing the same behavior on a Galaxy Tab 4

Comment: did anyone find something about this particular issue ?